# Getting PK value from data grid view

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a data loaded from database into dataGridView, with effect looking like this:

[image: Patients Data Grid View Sample]

(in final version I would prefer to hide the PatientID column)

What I'm trying to do, is return value of PatientID when user clicks ANYWHERE in the corresponding row (i.e. user clicks "Doe" and value returned is "2"). Could anyone give me a hint how to do this? I don't think there is valueMember property... I was trying Rowindex but that returns value of number of row counting from the top(D'uh?!)

Also, is there a way for user to highlight whole row when clicking on the single cell?

EDIT: Oh God, I've spent few hours late at night to find this, In the morning I gave up and posted here... just to find answer 5 minutes later:

```
string test = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["PatientID"].FormattedValue.ToString();
```

Still, that leaves my second question about highlighting whole row.

Answer (score 1):

If the datagridview is bound to some data source (`DataView`), you can use `DataBoundItem` property, for example

```
DGV.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem["PatientID"]
```

or

```
DGV.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem["PatientID"]
```

or

```
DGVUnderlyingBindingSource.Current["PatientID"]
```

If the DataGridView is bound to a strongly typed data source (e.g. `BindingList`) then you can use the above like this:

```
((PatientType)DGV.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem).PatientID
```

or

```
((PatientType)DGV.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem).PatientID
```

or

```
((PatientType)PatientTypeBindingSource.Current).PatientID
```

About the second part of the question, set the DataGridView's `SelectionMode` property to `FullRowSelect`

*EDIT*

You can't use the solution from your edit if you hide that column. In order to access the value by using `.Cells[idx].FormattedValue` that value must be visible. But you can use this one even if you hide the column.

Comment: dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem["device_id"] gives me Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: @cja I suppose you have a `DataView` as a DataSource. In that case you should just cast `DataBoundItem` to `DataRowView` like this: `((DataRowView)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem)["device_id"]`. You also need to cast the returned value itself. Since it's called "device_id" I suppose it's `int` so do this: `(int)((DataRowView)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem)["device_id"]`

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, set selection mode to FullRowSelect and the complete row will be highlighted when the user clicks on it.  You can set this attribute in the designer or code:

```
DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```